# If $G(x) = x^2 +4x$ find the values of $x$ that have $5$ as their image

Tags: functions

I don't know where to start I have tried using five to find the image but it doesn't give me the correct answer

Comment: I is not clear what your question is.

Comment: Well, to have five as their image means to find $\{x| x^2 + 4x = 5\}$.  So find all the solutions to $x^2 + 4x = 5$.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**: An image is the subset of a function's codomain which is the output of the function from a subset of its domain.

If $f : X → Y$ is a function from the set $X$ to the set $Y$, and if $x \in X$, then $f(x) = y$ is the image of $x$ under $f$.

So in our case, $x^2+4x =5 \Rightarrow x^2+4x-5=0 \Rightarrow (x+5)(x-1)=0$. Can you take it from here? Hope it helps.

Comment: So it would be x=-5 and x=1

Comment: @MahmudBugaje Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find the values of $x$ where $G(x) = x^2 + 4x$ equals 5. One can easily see that $x=1$ is a solution; the other one is $x=-5$. In any case, for quadratic equations you can't solve immediately, you can use the [ABC-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation).

Answer (score 0):

$G(x) = 5 \implies x^2 + 4x = 5 \implies  x^2 + 4x - 5 = 0$. By quadratic rule we have the values of $x = 1 , -5$.